# What is the difference between a normal HTTP request and a REST request

Tags: rest, http

I'm facing some issues in understanding the difference between a normal HTTP request and REST request. I've checked a few request and responses and they look the same to me. If they are indeed similar, how does the web service differentiate between a normal HTTP request and a REST request.

And yes, I know REST is an architecture style that defines how to use HTTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**REST** stands for **Re**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer. This architecture is *protocol independent* but it is *frequently* implemented over the HTTP protocol.

The REST architectural style was defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy Thomas Fielding's PhD dissertation (it's a must read if you are interested in REST). And the following set of constraints was added to this architectural style:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

A REST request (that can be a HTTP request when the REST architecture is implemented over the HTTP protocol) must contain all information to be understood by the server, without taking advantage of any stored context on the server.

For instance, if you are performing a request to a protected resource, that is, a resource that requires authentication, the request must contain the credentials to be properly authenticated. In REST there's no session state on server side.

That's how the REST [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) constraint is defined:

> [**5.1.3 Stateless**](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
>
> [...] each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. [...]

Comment: Ok. I got what you said. But, I want to know whether we can differentiate a normal HTTP request and a REST request. Like syntax-wise or content-wise.

Comment: @GovindMadhu When implementing a REST API over the HTTP protocol, your server expects HTTP requests. A request to your REST API will be a HTTP request.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the time you took to answer my query. I have one more question. I read somewhere that the WWW is based on REST architecture. Is this analogy valid?

Comment: @GovindMadhu If you have a new question, you could consider [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and add all the relevant details. I'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A REST request is not different to a HTTP request. The webservice doesn't have to figure out the type of request. Usually the webservice is deployed under a specific URL like `http://service.test.com?q=myquery` and with the GET data (as in this case) or POST data you can transmit specific data to the service.

Then a RESTful web service will usually return back a JSON or XML or something alike. The receiver of the webservice's response has to know what output to expect.